# How to avoid running next build flow in queue when the current build flow causes the slave machine to restart in between

Tags: jenkins

I have a build flow that restarts the machine in between.

build( "ATSMachineReimage" , MachineName: "q ")

build( "CheckForShutdown" , MachineName: "q" )

build( "SetupMachine", MachineName:"q")

build( "RestartMachine" , MachineName: "q" )

build( "CheckForShutdown" , MachineName: "q" )

build( "RunTest" , MachineName: "q")

Jenkins should wait until the the machine is up and finishes the next job("RunTest") in the build flow.

But in case there is another build flow waiting in the queue, Jenkins picks the next build flow as soon as the machine goes for a reboot.

Ideally it should finish the total build flow to proceed with the next build flow.

Answer (score 0):

if the problem is only when you have another queue build , you can clean the queue with a groovy script , and continue your flow.

you can modify this sample

```
import jenkins.model.*

def branchName = build.environment.get("GIT_BRANCH_NAME")

println "checking if need to clean the queue for" + branchName + "

println "=========before clean the queue ... =="

def q = Jenkins.instance.queue
q.items.each { 
  println("${it.task.name}:")
}

q.items.findAll { it.task.name.startsWith(branchName) }.each {     q.cancel(it.task) }
```

Comment: i was searching something in Jenkins like some plugins or some steps not  through groovy scripts. A way to lock the machine for the current build flow

Comment: bdw I dont want the build in queue to be cleaned. It should be executed after the current build flow gets finished.

Comment: so , you want to lock Jenkins for this specific flow ?